# how to do character control on w a s d?

Tags: javascript, game-development, keyboard-events

I made the mouse control, however, when I use **onkeydown** instead of **onmousedown**, the character moves for a few ms and stops, and when the button is released, the character gets into the idle animation.
How can i fix it?

This is my code for movement to right and to left:

```
const rightHandler = () => {
heroImg.style.transform = "scale(1,1)";
direction = "right";
spritePosition = spritePosition + 1;
imgBlockPosition = imgBlockPosition + 1;
if (spritePosition > 7) {
    spritePosition = 0;
}
heroImg.style.left = `-${spritePosition * 64}px`;
heroImg.style.top = '-64px';
imgBlock.style.left = `${imgBlockPosition * 7}px`;
}

const leftHandler = () => {
heroImg.style.transform = "scale(-1,1)";
direction = "left";
spritePosition = spritePosition - 1;
imgBlockPosition = imgBlockPosition - 1;
if (spritePosition < 7) {
    spritePosition = 13;
}
heroImg.style.left = `-${spritePosition * 64}px`;
heroImg.style.top = '-64px';
imgBlock.style.left = `${imgBlockPosition * 7}px`;
}
```

And this is code of onmousedown and onmouseup:

```
let onMouseDown = (event) => {
clearInterval(timer);
x = event.screenX;
timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (x > halfWidth) {
        direction = "right";
        rightHandler();
    }
    else {
        direction = "left";
        leftHandler();
    }
}, 100);
}

let onMouseUp = (event) => {
clearInterval(timer);
idleAnimation();
}
```

But when i use this code:

```
let onKeyDown = (event) => {
clearInterval(timer);
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (keyCode == 39) {
        direction = "right";
        rightHandler();
    }
    else if (keyCode == 37) {
        direction = "left";
        leftHandler();
    }
}, 100);
}

let onKeyUp = () => {
clearInterval(timer);
idleAnimation();
}
```

my character stops to move after few seconds.
What do i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

If you hold down the key, the `onpress` will constantly fire, clearing the interval and then setting up the interval, clearing it before it runs, setting up a new one, etc.

Use a boolean to keep track if a key has been pressed down. If it's pressed down, call another method that recursively calls itself.

Also, don't use `setInterval` if you want to animate because several calculations can happen between each screen update, and that will cause janky animation. Instead, use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Down below is an example of what it can look like:

```js
var keyPressed = -1;

const DIRECTIONS = {
  39: {direction: 1, name: "rightArrow"},
  37: {direction: -1, name: "leftArrow"}
}

let onKeyDown = (event) => {
  if (keyPressed == event.keyCode) { return }
  
  let keyCode = event.keyCode;
  
  if (DIRECTIONS[keyCode]) {
    move(DIRECTIONS[keyCode], keyCode);
  }
}

const move = (direction, keyCode) => {
  console.log(direction);
  
  if (keyCode == keyPressed) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => move(direction, keycode));
  }
}

let onKeyUp = (event) => {
  keyPressed = -1;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
```

```html
Click on this area, then hit left or right arrows.
```

Comment: There's a small error where if you press multiple keys but release one key, the other key will also count as released. And because only one condition can be true, you can't press W,D to move diagonally.

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes, but that's in the OP's code as well, so I didn't want to do anything fancy that wasn't asked for.